# Does vue 3 loads css multiple times if we call same component in single page? If not how does it work?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

My vue 3 component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineAsyncComponent, ref, Ref } from "vue";
import CookiesHelper from "@/utilities/cookies";
import { Banner as BannerType } from "@/interfaces/Banner";
import { usePackageStore } from "@/store/offers-package";
import { useInitDataStore } from "@/store/init-data";
import useGroupedData from "@/composables/grouped-data";


CookiesHelper.setCookies();

const isLoaded = ref(false);
const dataStore = usePackageStore();
const initDataStore = useInitDataStore();

let selectedApp: unknown;

switch (initDataStore.app) {
  case "app1":
    selectedApp = defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/pages/app1.vue"));
    break;
  default:
    selectedApp = defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/pages/app2.vue"));
}

dataStore
  .setDataPackage()
  .then(() => {
    isLoaded.value = true;
  })
  .catch((e: Error) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
</script>

<template>
  <div v-show="isLoaded">
    <component :is="selectedApp"></component>
    <link-tracking></link-tracking>
    <link-tracking></link-tracking>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

I want to understand, if **link-tracking** component has scoped css, then that css will be loaded only once or twice? how does this actually gets compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That CSS will be loaded only once as well as JS for that component.

You can have as many **instances** of each component on the page, it only needs to be **defined once**. Scoped or not scoped styles makes no difference in this context, Vue will generate same hashed data attribute that it will apply to each instance of a component and it will be used to scope CSS to that component.